# Ctypes arguments called with not enough arguments

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to import and use the function of a c++ dll with ctypes. The function is called successfully with windll, but keep showing ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing) when passing arguments. I ruled out all the possibility and pretty sure I'm using the correct calling convention. Change to oledll or cdll won't help either. Below is the code, and also the user manual for the dll function calling. Thanks.

[dll user manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9tP.png)

Code:

```
from ctypes import *

biometric = windll.LoadLibrary(r"G:\software\datalite\OnLineInterface.dll")

i = c_long(1)
biometric.OnLineGetData.argtypes = [c_long,c_long,POINTER(c_long)]
b = pointer(i)
biometric.OnLineGetData(c_long(1),c_long(1),b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's from *Biometrics*' *DataLINK* *API* which is also documented at [[NI.Forums]: Manual1.pdf](http://forums.ni.com/attachments/ni/170/241688/1/Manual1.pdf). According to that (and the image in the question as well), the function prototype is:

```c
int __stdcall OnLineGetData(long channel, long sizeMsToRead, SAFEARRAY **DataArray, long *pActualSamples);
```

So, you're missing the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument (the double pointer: `SAFEARRAY **DataArray`). Unfortunately, that's "a bit" more complicated (one possible reason for you skipping it :) ). 
I prepared a small (and dummy) example (I also included the *SAFEARRAY* creation, but there are parts (*sample_rate*) that need to be clarified for it to work properly, and also, I didn't test it).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt


class SAFEARRAYBOUND(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cElements", wt.ULONG),
        ("LONG", wt.LONG),
    ]


class SAFEARRAY(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cDims", wt.USHORT),
        ("fFeatures", wt.USHORT),
        ("cbElements", wt.ULONG),
        ("cLocks", wt.ULONG),
        ("pvData", ct.c_void_p),
        ("rgsabound", SAFEARRAYBOUND * 1),
    ]

PSAFEARRAY = ct.POINTER(SAFEARRAY)
PPSAFEARRAY = ct.POINTER(PSAFEARRAY)


def main(*argv):
    mod_name = r"G:\software\datalite\OnLineInterface.dll"
    #mod_name = "kernel32"
    OnLineInterfaceDll = ct.WinDLL(mod_name)
    OnLineGetData = OnLineInterfaceDll.OnLineGetData
    OnLineGetData.argtypes = (ct.c_long, ct.c_long, PPSAFEARRAY, ct.POINTER(ct.c_long))
    OnLineGetData.restype = ct.c_int

    OleAut32Dll = ct.WinDLL("OleAut32.dll")
    SafeArrayDestroy = OleAut32Dll.SafeArrayDestroy
    SafeArrayDestroy.argtypes = (PSAFEARRAY,)
    SafeArrayDestroy.restype = ct.c_long
    # Not quite sure how to initialize the SAFEARRAY, you'll have to search for C examples doing that.
    # There is SafeArrayCreate function, but given the double pointer, I think that's called from within OnLineGetData
    # However, I assume that freing the pointer is your responsibility (hence SafeArrayDestroy).

    channel = 1
    millis = 1
    samples = ct.c_long(-1)

    create_array = 1
    if create_array:
        # Create the array according to (available) docs. Needless to say that I didn't test it
        print("Creating array")
        SafeArrayCreateVector = OleAut32Dll.SafeArrayCreateVector
        SafeArrayCreateVector.argtypes = (ct.c_ushort, wt.LONG, wt.ULONG)
        SafeArrayCreateVector.restype = PSAFEARRAY

        VT_I2 = 2
        sample_rate = 5  # !!! PLACE AN APPROPRIATE VALUE (GOT FROM THE DEVICE) HERE !!!
        psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_I2, 0, millis * sample_rate)
        #print(psa)
        ppsa = ct.pointer(psa)
        #print(ppsa)
    else:
        print("Using dummy array")
        ppsa = PPSAFEARRAY()  # Dummy double pointer

    res = OnLineGetData(channel, millis, ppsa, ct.byref(samples))
    print("\n{0:s} returned: {1:d}".format(OnLineGetData.__name__, res))
    if ppsa:
        print("Doing smth with the data:", ppsa.contents)
        SafeArrayDestroy(ppsa.contents)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

Comment: I gotten the codes work as provided by you. However, I'm now stuggle with the SAFEARRAY, as I read up a the documents about SAFEARRAY, indeed it will need the strcuture declaration as inyour code, but apparently in C a SafeArrayCreate function to initialize the safearray. This function is not supported in ctypes nor Python, is it possible to initialize SAFEARRAY for ctypes in Python? There is only a few discussion on internet.

Comment: It is possible to call it, it's in *oleaut32.dll*. But as I said I think that the func is called internally by *OnLineGetData*. But the *SafeArrayCreate* call from *CTypes* could be the topic of another question.

Comment: Update: The double pointer pass through the function return booleon value of false. So I assume that the  function doesn't create safearray for the pointer adress.

Comment: In other words, can I understand as the function itself will create a safearray when passing null pointer?